# Convert sweet.js argument into string

Tags: sweet.js

How would you create a string from an argument to a sweet.js macro? For example:

```
let foo = macro {
    rule {
        $name
    } => {
        console.log('$name', $name);
    }
}

var x = 42;

foo x
```

Will output:

```
console.log(x, x);
```

When I'd prefer it to output:

```
console.log('x', x);
```

So the first argument has quotes around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a case macro:

```
let foo = macro {
    case {_
        $name
    } => {
        letstx $name_str = [makeValue(unwrapSyntax(#{$name}), #{here})];
        return #{
            console.log($name_str, $name);
        }
    }
}

var x = 42;

foo x
```

The basic idea is that you make a new string token (via `makeValue`) using the string value of the identifiers mached by `$name` (`unwrapSyntax` gives us the value of the given syntax objects, in the case of identifiers it is the identifier string). Then `letstx` allows us to bind our newly created syntax object for use inside the `#{}` template.

Comment: Excellent, I thought I might have to use a case macro but every time I tried to work out how I ended up with syntax errors but your explanation clears it up nicely